# timer_create() not able to catch a signal in handler function

Tags: c, linux, signals, handler

Here i am trying achieve a timer say 0-10secs and an interval of 2secs each,so that i need to generate an interrupt @ every 2secs(total 5 times) saying 2secs completed. which i have been cross checking in handler() function by using printf(). But i am not able to achieve the desired result.please put me touch if anyone is aware of it.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIGTIMER                                (SIGRTMAX)
       #define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                               } while (0)



        void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
       {
                      printf("Caught signal %d\n", sig);

       }

       int
       main(int argc, char *argv[])
       {
           timer_t timerid;
           struct sigevent sev;
           struct itimerspec its;
           struct itimerspec oitval;

           struct sigaction sa;

           /* Establish handler for timer signal */

           printf("Establishing handler for signal %d\n", SIGTIMER);
           sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
           sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
           sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
           if (sigaction(SIGTIMER, &sa, NULL) == -1)
               errExit("sigaction");

           /* Create the timer */

           sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
           sev.sigev_signo = SIGTIMER;
           sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
           if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerid) == 0)
           {
           printf("timer ID is 0x%lx\n", (long) timerid);

           /* Start the timer */

           its.it_value.tv_sec = 10;
           its.it_value.tv_nsec =0;
           its.it_interval.tv_sec =   2;
           its.it_interval.tv_nsec =  0;

           if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, &oitval) == -1)
                errExit("timer_settime");
           }
           else
           {
              errExit("timer_create");
           }

           return 0;
       }
```

Comment: "*... I am not able to achieve the desired result*" but observe exactly what?

Comment: I have used printf() just for the testing purpose but then Thanks a lot alk for your comments, now its working fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should properly setup timeouts:

```
       /* Start the timer */

       its.it_value.tv_sec     = 2;
       its.it_value.tv_nsec    = 0;
       its.it_interval.tv_sec  = 2;
       its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
```

`it_value` is the duration before first triggering, and `it_interval` is time between all subsequent triggerings. See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html). Then, you shouldn't return from `main()` due it leads to process exit and you won't be able to observe timer ticks. You need to block execution somehow, e.g.

```
while(1) sleep(INT_MAX);
```

After each tick `sleep()` returns with `errno` set to `EINTR` so it should we wrapped into loop to allow timer to go ahead. Later you can decide when to leave this loop and exit.

P.S. Using `printf()` from signal handler is not a good idea. You should be very carefully with what you are doing there. It would be better just to write to some global variable and immediately return. And that var may be tested immediately after `sleep()` giving you an idea if you should sleep again or return.